# NEO4J/Cypher: Use result as condition for new create

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i want to create a new node based on a return result in cypher. I cant figure out how to use CASE here(I guess thats what i need?)

I shorted the code because the above part is not important. I get a true or false in "result" and want to use this information to create a new node.

......

```
RETURN ((sum(r.rooms)+_rooms)<=a.allocation and count(r)>0) as result
```

If true then:

```
CREATE (s:SOMETHING)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on [the WITH clause](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/). This is similar to RETURN, except it allows you to continue the query. It's used for cases like this, where you need to aggregate or project out or control what's in scope (only the variables you include in the WITH clause are kept in scope afterwards) and continue the query past it.

```
...
WITH ((sum(r.rooms)+_rooms)<=a.allocation and count(r)>0) as result
WHERE result
CREATE (s:SOMETHING)
```